# Update array passed by reference with BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, pass-by-reference, indirection

I would like to write a function that takes an array variable name and updates the contents.  For example:

```
ARRAY1=("test 1" "test 2" "test 3")
toUpper ARRAY1

for arg in "${ARRAY1[@]}"; do
  echo "arg=$arg"
done

# output
arg=TEST 1
arg=TEST 2
arg=TEST 3
```

I have a crude attempt at doing this which requires a copy of the input array.  Using indirect references, I am able to create a copy of the input variable.  The copy of the array is used to get the count of the elements.  If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

```
function toUpper() {
  local ARRAY_NAME=$1
  local ARRAY_REF="$ARRAY_NAME[@]"
  # use an indirect reference to copy the array so we can get the count
  declare -a ARRAY=("${!ARRAY_REF}")

  local COUNT=${#ARRAY[@]}

  for ((i=0; i<$COUNT; i++)); do
    local VAL="${ARRAY[$i]}"
    VAL=$(echo $VAL | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
    echo "ARRAY[$i]=\"$VAL\""
    eval "$ARRAY_NAME[$i]=\"$VAL\""
  done
}

ARRAY1=( "test" "test 1" "test 3" )

toUpper ARRAY1

echo
echo "Printing array contents"
for arg in "${ARRAY1[@]}"; do
  echo "arg=$arg"
done
```

Comment: What is your BASH version?

Comment: Using BASH 4 but would be nice if the solution would work with version 3 if possible.

Comment: BTW, all-uppercase variable names for non-exported shell variables is bad form. Per the POSIX spec (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html): "The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications"; since environment and local variables share a namespace, using lower-case names prevents overwriting environment variables and builtins by accident.

Comment: As an aside -- the `function` keyword is best avoided. It has no semantic use -- `function foo() { ...; }` has precisely the same effect as `foo() { ...; }` in bash -- but needlessly makes code incompatible with POSIX sh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using **BASH 4.3+** you can do

```
arr=( "test" "test 1" "test 3" )
toUpper() { declare -n tmp="$1"; printf "%s\n" "${tmp[@]^^}"; }

toUpper arr
TEST
TEST 1
TEST 3
```

**Update:** To reflect the changes in original array:

```
toUpper() {
   declare -n tmp="$1"; 
   for ((i=0; i<"${#tmp[@]}"; i++)); do
      tmp[i]="${tmp[i]^^}"
    done;
}

arr=( "test" "test 1" "test 3" )
toUpper arr
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
TEST
TEST 1
TEST 3
```

---

**Update2:** Here is a way to make it work in **older BASH (prior to 4)** versions without `eval`:

```
upper() {
   len=$2
   for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do
      elem="${1}[$i]"
      val=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "${!elem}")
      IFS= read -d '' -r "${1}[$i]" < <(printf '%s\0' "$val")
   done;
}

arr=( "test" "test 1" "test 3" )
upper arr ${#arr[@]}
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
TEST
TEST 1
TEST 3
```

Comment: Printing the contents is easy, I'm trying to update the values in the source array.

Comment: See updated code for updating changes in calling array.

Comment: Not just 4+, but 4.3+; that said, when targeting a new enough bash, this is certainly the best choice.

Comment: I'm using bash 4.1.2 - can you comment on what specifically in your script only works with 4.3?

Comment: I believe it is `declare -n` (reference variable) that was added in 4.3

Comment: Check my **Update2** for a way to do it in older bash versions (<4.3) without using eval.

Comment: I'd suggest using `read -r` if not wanting to have side effects on the data (expanding backslash escape sequences).

Comment: Also, why the unquoted expansion in the `read` command? Not that it's going to be harmful for a typical variable name, but does it serve any purpose?

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, Yes using `read -r` will be safe. I changes quotes a bit however since `$1` is just the name of the array which would be some alphanumeric string.

Comment: (Actually, setting `-d ''` might also be appropriate, to avoid truncating data at embedded linebreaks -- and clearing IFS to avoid removing trailing whitespace).

Comment: Quoting `[:lower:]` and `[:upper:]` may also be appropriate, to prevent those strings from being glob-matched before being passed to `tr`. I note that I made the same mistake there myself.

Comment: @anubhava, if we don't want to truncate at the first newline in the string. IFS controls characters used for trimming words, and characters considered whitespace to be trimmed from the end; `-d` controls the characters which ends the content read by a single invocation of `read`. Compare `IFS= read -r <<<$'one\ntwo'; printf '%q\n' "$REPLY"` and `IFS= read -r -d '' <<<$'one\ntwo'; printf '%q\n' "${REPLY%$'\n'}"`.

Comment: ...although that _does_ point out a problem with using `<<<`, which implicitly adds a (single) trailing newline. `< <(printf %s "$val")` would avoid that bug.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @CharlesDuffy, This `<<<` adding `\n` was bugging me.

Comment: One revision to my prior suggestion -- `printf '%s\0'` would be better than `printf '%s'`, since with its expected delimiter present, `read` will have an exit status of 0 rather than 1, avoiding problems if `set -e` or an ERR trap is in use.

Comment: btw, it really needs to be `-d ''`, with a space before the empty string; `-d''` is precisely the same as `-d` (indistinguishable once the argument vector is handed off to the command), so `-d'' -r` makes `-` be the delimiter, and ignores the intended behavior of `-r`.

Answer (score 1):

anubhava's answer is ideal for bash 4.3 or newer. To support bash 3, one can use `eval` (very cautiously, with strings generated with `printf %q`) to replace the use of namevars, and `tr` to replace the `${foo^^}` expansion for upper case:

```
toUpper() {
  declare -a indexes
  local cmd idx item result
  printf -v cmd 'indexes=( "${!%q[@]}" )' "$1"; eval "$cmd"
  for idx in "${indexes[@]}"; do
     printf -v cmd 'item=${%q[%q]}' "$1" "$idx"; eval "$cmd"
     result=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$item")
     printf -v cmd '%q[%q]=%q' "$1" "$idx" "$result"; eval "$cmd"
  done
}
```

Comment: (Notably, in newer versions of bash, `printf -v` can assign directly to an array element; however, that's a 4.2 feature, not available in 3.x -- but still can be helpful if one isn't _quite_ running 4.3).