# Bash - check if argument is string

Tags: bash

I am attempting to check if an argument is an array with the following code:

```
if [[ $(declare -p $1) ]] != *-a*;
```

Here $1 is a string with the value "123". I get the following error message from bash:

```
`arrays.bash: line 23: declare: 123: not found
```

This code works if I pass an array as an argument but not a string. I want to verify that the argument is either an array or an associative array. I have no concern with the contents at this point, I only want the type. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: `$1` is always a string. Always. It cannot be anything else. That also means it cannot be an array.

Comment: One could pass a string _with the name of an array_ in `$1`, but it's still a string.

Comment: Anyhow -- the code in your question checks what kind of variable the string in `$1` refers to, with the assumption that the string is in fact a variable name; it's falling when you aren't passing a variable name at all. This is to be expected.

Comment: Then why does it work when I pass an array? Interpreting the declare expression gives a string. if it is an array it contains the substring "-a" which is the flag that would have been used on the original declaration of the variable that references an array.  A different string is produced for a string variable. I also tried it with a string variable with the same result. There is also the possibility of an integer being passed as an argument which would be incorrect.

Comment: How do you pass a variable name in Bash?

Comment: _How_ are you passing the array? The typical approach is `yourfunction "${arrayname[@]}"`, which makes the first element of the array be `$1`, the second be `$2`, etc -- they're still all strings, and it's one argument per element, not one argument for the whole array.

Comment: The other approach is `yourfunction arrayname`; at that point `$1` is a string, but you can use namevars or other indirect reference mechanisms to refer to the array the string names.

Comment: One of the things you _don't_ do is `yourfunction "$arrayname"`, which only passes the first element of the array and ignores all the others (in bash and ksh93; zsh is different, this is one of the reasons tagging for the correct shell is important).

Comment: ...regardless, you aren't providing a [mre] showing us how you're defining the array and how you're trying to pass it; from the question I don't even know that you're using a real array at all (we get a lot of n00bs using strings that contain whitespace and calling them arrays), much less how you're attempting to pass it.

Comment: Anyhow, one place you might start is [Update array passed by reference with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473368/update-array-passed-by-reference-with-bash); your needs may be simpler, but going direct to the most complex case means you're covered for easier ones as well.

Comment: Also potentially of interest is [Passing multiple distinct arrays to a shell function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953833/passing-multiple-distinct-arrays-to-a-shell-function).

Comment: ...anyhow, if you go the `yourfunction arrayname` approach, your `declare -p` code will work.

Comment: That said, note that there's a lot in common between how bash treats a string and how the shell treats a single-element array. After `stringvar=value`, running `"${stringvar[@]}"` evaluates to the exact same thing as `"${stringvar[0]}"` or `"$stringvar"`, similar to how `array=( "first element" "second element" )` sets up `"$array"` to be identical to `"${array[0]}"` (again, if your shell really is bash; zsh will differ).

Comment: Charles Duffy, if the array was named x I am simply passing x. At a later point in this function, I will become interested in the contents but not now. I am simply trying to tell the caller that the wrong type of data was passed as an argument.

Comment: Again, we need an actual [mre]. I don't know when you say "passing c" you mean `yourfunc c` or `yourfunc "$c"` or `yourfunc "${c[@]}"` or something else. Runnable code is far more precise than English-language descriptions of code.

Comment: c was a typo that I corrected.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you just need to check if the variable _exists_ before checking which type it is. `[[ -v "$1" ]] || { echo "ERROR: required a variable name as first argument" >&2; return 1; }` and _then_ when that's done do your `declare -p` check.

Comment: But you really should [edit] the question to make it more clear: it's not appropriate for folks to answer based on content that's only present in comments.

Comment: (or, as suggested in a comment on Cyrus's answer, just put a `2>/dev/null` on your `declare -p`s, and there you are -- no error)

Comment: The code shown won't work work; you have the `!= *-a*` *outside* the `[[ ... ]]` when it should be *inside*. As shown, you'll get a syntax error before you get any errors involving `declare`.

Answer (score 1):

After all, why worry about the types, if you are relying on it perhaps your approach is wrong or you may need a strong-typed language

```
% v=1
% declare -p v
declare -- v="1"
% echo $v
1
% echo ${v[@]}
1
% v[1]=2
% declare -p v
declare -a v=([0]="1" [1]="2")
% echo ${v[@]}
1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Error In The Question

You called `yourfunction "$a"` instead of `yourfunction a`, when `a=123`. Don't do that: You need to pass the *name* of the variable, not its value.

---

### General Solution: Bash 5.x+

Bash 5 has a new feature called *parameter transformation*, whereby `${parameter@operator}` can perform a variety of actions; one of these is checking the type of the parameter.

```
myfunc() {
  [[ -v "$1" ]] || { echo "No variable named $1 exists" >&2; return 1; }
  case ${!1@a} in
    *a*) echo "Array";;
    *A*) echo "Associative array";;
    *i*) echo "Integer";;
    "")  echo "Default string";;
    *)   echo "Other/unknown flag set: ${!1@a}";;
  esac
}
```

---

### Older Solution

```
myfunc() {
  local typedesc
  typedesc=$(declare -p "$1" 2>/dev/null) || {
    echo "No variable named $1 is set" >&2
    return 1
  }
  case $typedesc in
    "declare -a"*) echo "Array";;
    "declare -A"*) echo "Associative array";;
    "declare -i"*) echo "Integer";;
    "declare --"*) echo "Regular (default) string variable";;
    *)             echo "Other/unrecognized type";;
  esac
}
```